# Equivalent definition of real interpolation space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, interpolation-spaces

In one of his papers (*On the Nash-Moser implicit function theorem*, Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn., Ser. A I, Math. 10, 255-259 (1985).), Lars Hörmander introduces a class of function spaces that seems related to real interpolation theory but I could not get the precise relation.

Here is his definition:

Assume given $(E_0, \|\cdot\|_0)$ and $(E_1, \|\cdot\|_1)$ two Banach spaces with $E_1$ continuously embedded into $E_0$ and a strictly increasing sequence $(\theta_j)_{j\geq 0}$, with $\theta_0 = 1$, such that $\theta_{j+1}/\theta_j$ is bounded.

We set $\Delta_j = \theta_{j+1}-\theta_j$.

For any $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, we let $E'_\alpha$ be the set of elements $u$ of $E_1$ such that there exist a constant $M$ and a sequence $(u_j)_{j\geq 0}$ of elements of $E_1$ so that
$$
u = \sum_j \Delta_j u_j \quad\text{in } E_0
$$
and such that,
$$
\forall j\geq 0, \|u_j\|_0 \leq M\theta_j^{-\alpha-1}\text{ and } \|u_j\|_1 \leq M\theta_j^{-\alpha}
$$
For such a $u$, we let $\|u\|'_{\alpha}$ be the infimum of the values of $M$ for which such a decomposition exists.

We recall here the definition of the real interpolation space (following A. Lunardi, *Analytic semigroups and optimal regularity in parabolic problems*):
For any $u \in E_0$ and $t > 0$, we set
$$
K(t, u) = \inf \{\|a\|_0 + t \|b\|_1 \vert (a, b) \in E_0 \times E_1, u = a+b\},
$$
$$
\|u\|_{(E_0, E_1)_{\alpha, \infty}} = \|t^{-1} K(t, u)\|_{L^\infty((0,\infty), \mathbb{R})},
$$
and define
$$
(E_0, E_1)_{\alpha, \infty} = \{u \in E_0, \|u\|_{(E_0, E_1)_{\alpha, \infty}} < \infty\}.
$$
This is a Banach space when endowed with the norm $\|\cdot\|_{(E_0, E_1)_{\alpha, \infty}}$.

It is pretty easy to see that $E'_\alpha$ embeds continuously into $(E_0, E_1)_{\alpha, \infty}$ but I have been unable to prove the converse embedding.

Is it true that $(E_0, E_1)_{\alpha, \infty} = E'_\alpha$ and that the norms are equivalent?

If so this would make available all results from interpolation theorem and in particular show that the definition given by Hörmander is independent of the choice of the sequence $(\theta_j)_j$.